# how to change border color of colorbox

Tags: jquery, css, border, colorbox

Hi I am using [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) throughout my web application. I wonder if I can change the border color of my color box. I have gone through the code and see that there is a attribute

```
 #cboxMiddleLeft:background: url("images/controls.png") repeat-y scroll left top transparent;
```

and when I go to images folder of color box I see a controls.png image for left and right borders of the color box and property

```
 #cboxBottomCenter: background: url("images/border.png") repeat-x scroll 0 -29px transparent;
```

for top and bottom borders of the color box. Both images are in `dark grey color`.

Now what I want to ask that If I want to change the border of the color box, then should I put the `color.png and border.png` in that particular color? Can I get these images in all colors? Because its difficult to design the same images in all colors.

The color of my web application changes in many colors and I want to show borders with respect to those colors. What is the best approach for this? Is there any automated way to do this? I searched but couldn't get any thing.

Regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about hiding all of the

```
$("#cboxTopLeft").hide();
$("#cboxTopRight").hide();
$("#cboxBottomLeft").hide();
$("#cboxBottomRight").hide();
$("#cboxMiddleLeft").hide();
$("#cboxMiddleRight").hide();
$("#cboxTopCenter").hide();
$("#cboxBottomCenter").hide();
```

Or just specify in the plugin that you want no border; next add the following css

```
.blue_border_example {
    border: 10px solid blue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px blue;
}
```

Then add this class to `#cboxContent` like:

```
$("#cboxContent").addClass("blue_border_example");
```

Comment: thanks for this post and can u please tell me, how to hide the background of the colorbox while the transition effect is showing? i mean when i click on a button i'm successful in opening the colorbox with the content what i want in it & also succeeded in hiding the colorbox backgrounds in my page, now what i want is not to show the colorbox background when the content is loading to display(in the transition effect time)?? can u please let me know how can i do that in the similar way as above hide functions..

Comment: `$("#cboxOverlay").hide();` Is this what you mean?

Comment: hehe no problem! It always helps to right click, inspect element.